# Connecting to server with String Token

Tags: android, server

I am working personal project with friends.

The application needs login, when login is successfully done, the server response token to me.
After I got token, he said if I send token with "GET" request method to specific api of the server, it will return all information of a user such as id, pwd, email, and address.

I tried to send token to server but it cannot read.

What can I do to solve this problem?
here is my code sending token to server.

```
URL url = new URL(BASE_URL);
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
                
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(serverMessage);
String userToken = jsonObject.getString("token");
                
connection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + userToken);
connection.connect();
Log.i(TAG, "Token = " + userToken);

OutputStream outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));
writer.write(userToken);
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do

```
     connection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + userToken);
```

Do it

```
    connection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer ".concat( userToken));
```

i hope it works.

Comment: No it is not working. error message seems like only one character is input to server.

{"message":"Unexpected token e in JSON at position 0","stack":"SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 0\n ...

Comment: show full code and which lib use for server?

Comment: I am using just HttpURLConnection now.
code is too long to paste here

Comment: better to move third party lib for this, then you dont face any issue ,as like volley,Fast android networking,retrofit etc..

Comment: If I move to Volley, how can I match token to server header req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer') ?

Comment: it look like this below

Comment: Thanks. I'll try then tell you

Comment: https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking   use this it help you a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
      RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
      String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/users/self/blogs";
     StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
    new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            // handle response
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toasty.warning(SelectBlog.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}){
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

        params.put("Authorization", "Bearer ".concat( userToken));

        return params;
    }
};

queue.add(stringRequest);
```